# floatcanvas toolbar exact fit sample - worked in python 2, no longer working in 3 w/latest wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

The main issue is that the toolbar doesn't open anymore. The original goal was to hide/show the toolbar when the user leaves/enters the window/canvas along w/an exact fit app.

The following code worked w/FloatCanvas & Python 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

# #import the installed version
# from wx.lib.floatcanvas import NavCanvas, FloatCanvas

# import a local version
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
from floatcanvas import NavCanvas, FloatCanvas

# Set a path to an Image file here:
ImageFile = "./white_tank.jpg"

class DrawFrame(wx.Frame):

    """
    A frame used for the FloatCanvas Demo

    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args,
                   style=wx.FRAME_SHAPED
                   | wx.SIMPLE_BORDER
                   | wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR
        )
        # self.CreateStatusBar()

        # Add the Canvas

        self.CanvasNav = NavCanvas.NavCanvas(self,
                                     ProjectionFun=None,
                                     style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW,
                                     # BackgroundColor=(255, 255, 255, 0),
                                    #  BackgroundColor="DARK SLATE BLUE",
                                     )

        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Hide()
        Canvas = self.CanvasNav.Canvas
        Canvas.MaxScale = 4
        self.Canvas = Canvas

        FloatCanvas.EVT_MOTION(self.Canvas, self.OnMove)
        self.CanvasNav.ZoomButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ZoomToFit)

        # create the image:
        image = wx.Image(ImageFile)
        img = Canvas.AddScaledBitmap(image,
                                     (0, 0),
                                     Height=image.GetHeight(),
                                     Position='tl',
                                     Quality='normal',
                                    )
        self.image = image
        self.set_size(image)
        img.Bind(FloatCanvas.EVT_FC_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        img.Bind(FloatCanvas.EVT_FC_MOTION, self.OnMotion)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE, self.OnMove)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnLeave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnEnter)


        self.Show()
        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Show()
        Canvas.ZoomToBB(margin_adjust=1.2)

        self.move_count = 0

    def ZoomToFit(self, e):
        self.set_size(self.image)
        self.Canvas.ZoomToBB(margin_adjust=1.2)

    def set_size(self, image):
        """
        adjusts the size of the window to fit the aspect ration of the image
        """
        # compute the aspect ratio of the image
        w, h = image.GetSize()
        ar = float(w) / float(h)

        # check the size of this window
        w, h = self.GetSize()
        print w, h
        # adjust the width to get the rigth aspect ratio
        w = int(h * ar)
        self.SetSize( (w, h) )
        print "reset size to:"
        print self.GetSize()

    def OnEnter(self, e):
        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Show()
        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Realize()

    def OnLeave(self, e):
        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Hide()
        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Realize()

    def OnMove(self, event):
        """
        Updates the status bar with the world coordinates

        """
        # self.SetStatusText("%i, %i" % tuple(event.Coords))

    def OnLeftDown(self, obj):
        print "Left Mouse Clicked on ", obj

    def OnMotion(self, obj):
        print "mouse moving on image:", self.move_count
        self.move_count += 1

app = wx.App(False)
F = DrawFrame(None, title="FloatCanvas Demo App", size=(700, 700))
app.MainLoop()
```

Here's my attempt to get it to work the same way using the latest Python & wxPython, but am having issues w/the toolbar (also getting KeyError on line 64).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

# #import the installed version
# from wx.lib.floatcanvas import NavCanvas, FloatCanvas

# import a local version
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
try:
    from floatcanvas import NavCanvas, FloatCanvas, Resources
except ImportError: # if it's not there locally, try the wxPython lib.
    from wx.lib.floatcanvas import NavCanvas, FloatCanvas, Resources

# Set a path to an Image file here:
# ImageFile = "C:\\Users\\alex\\Downloads\\white_tank.jpg"
ImageFile = "white_tank.jpg"

class DrawFrame(wx.Frame):

    """
    A frame used for the FloatCanvas Demo

    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args,
                   style=wx.FRAME_SHAPED
                   | wx.SIMPLE_BORDER
                   | wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR
        )
        # self.CreateStatusBar()

        # Add the Canvas

        self.CanvasNav = NavCanvas.NavCanvas(self,
                                     ProjectionFun=None,
                                     style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW,
                                     # BackgroundColor=(255, 255, 255, 0),
                                    #  BackgroundColor="DARK SLATE BLUE",
                                     )

        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Hide()
        Canvas = self.CanvasNav.Canvas
        Canvas.MaxScale = 4
        self.Canvas = Canvas

        FloatCanvas.EVT_MOTION(self.Canvas, self.OnMove)
        self.CanvasNav.ZoomButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ZoomToFit)

        # create the image:
        image = wx.Image(ImageFile)
        img = Canvas.AddScaledBitmap(image,
                                     (0, 0),
                                     Height=image.GetHeight(),
                                     Position='tl',
                                    #  Quality='normal',
                                    )
        self.image = image
        self.set_size(image)
        img.Bind(FloatCanvas.EVT_FC_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        # img.Bind(FloatCanvas.EVT_FC_MOTION, self.OnMotion)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOVE, self.OnMove)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnLeave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnEnter)


        self.Show()
        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Show()
        Canvas.ZoomToBB(margin_adjust=1.2)

        self.move_count = 0

    def ZoomToFit(self, e):
        self.set_size(self.image)
        self.Canvas.ZoomToBB(margin_adjust=1.2)

    def set_size(self, image):
        """
        adjusts the size of the window to fit the aspect ration of the image
        """
        # compute the aspect ratio of the image
        w, h = image.GetSize()
        ar = float(w) / float(h)

        # check the size of this window
        w, h = self.GetSize()
        print(w, h)
        # adjust the width to get the rigth aspect ratio
        w = int(h * ar)
        self.SetSize( (w, h) )
        print("reset size to:")
        print(self.GetSize())

    def OnEnter(self, e):
        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Show()
        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Realize()

    def OnLeave(self, e):
        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Hide()
        self.CanvasNav.ToolBar.Realize()

    def OnMove(self, event):
        """
        Updates the status bar with the world coordinates

        """
        # self.SetStatusText("%i, %i" % tuple(event.Coords))

    def OnLeftDown(self, obj):
        print("Left Mouse Clicked on ", obj)

    def OnMotion(self, obj):
        print("mouse moving on image:", self.move_count)
        self.move_count += 1

app = wx.App(False)
F = DrawFrame(None, title="FloatCanvas Demo App", size=(700, 700))
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working using python 3.6.7 and wxpython 4.0.3 gtk2 but fails when using wxpython 4.0.1 gtk3. [On Linux]
You failed to specify your OS and the version of wx that you are using.
If we assume that you are using 4.0.1 gtk3 the answer is to change the style of the `DrawFrame` from

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args,style=wx.FRAME_SHAPED| wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)| wx.FRAME_NO_TASKBAR)
```

to

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args)
```

Note also that `margin_adjust` in `Canvas.ZoomToBB(margin_adjust=1.2)` is now invalid.

I would also worry about the fact that you are trying to import a local version of `floatcanvas`

```
sys.path.append("../")
try:
    from floatcanvas import NavCanvas, FloatCanvas, Resources
except ImportError: # if it's not there locally, try the wxPython lib.
    from wx.lib.floatcanvas import NavCanvas, FloatCanvas, Resources
```

Comment: Thanks, Rolf!
That got things going in the right direction.
The workaround now is to set self.SetWindowStyle w/in OnEnter/OnLeave.